# convert array to multiple object based on options array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object and each object has mutiple options, how to covert the it to multiple objects based on the options count?

Input:

```js
var arr =   [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]

const res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc,{name, options})=>{
  acc[name] = acc[name] || {name, options: []};
  acc[name].options.push(options);
  return acc;
}, {}));
console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Expected Output:

```
[{name: "audio", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "audio", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}},
{name: "audio", options:{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}},
{name: "video", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'true', value: 'T'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'No', value: 'N'}},
{name: "call", options:{name:'false', value: 'F'}}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a flat map

```js
const arr = [{"name":"audio","options":[{"name":"true","value":"T"},{"name":"false","value":"F"},{"name":"yes","value":"Y"}]},{"name":"video","options":[{"name":"true","value":"T"},{"name":"false","value":"F"},{"name":"yes","value":"Y"}]},{"name":"call","options":[{"name":"true","value":"T"},{"name":"false","value":"F"},{"name":"yes","value":"Y"}]}]

const res = arr.flatMap(({ options, ...props }) =>
  options.map(options => ({ ...props, options })))

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This creates an array of arrays for each `options` in the collection and then flattens it to produce a one-dimensional array.

The spread syntax lets you merge any top-level properties (like `name`) into each *option* result

Answer (score 1):

You need a nested loop over the `options` array to split them into separate array elements.

```js
var arr =   [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]

const res = [];

arr.forEach(({
  name,
  options
}) => options.forEach(option => res.push({
  name,
  options: option
})));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the converted elements, then use
[Array.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to flatten the 2D array.

```js
var arr =   [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]

let output = arr.map(it => {
  return it.options.map(option => {
    return {name:it.name,options:option}
  })
}).flat()

console.log(output);
```

**Edit:**

As @mplungjan mentioned this is identical to using [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap).

```js
var arr =   [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]

let output = arr.flatMap(it => {
  return it.options.map(option => {
    return {name:it.name,options:option}
  })
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Or use flatMap..

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr =   [{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]

const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc = [...acc, ...cur.options.map(option => {
        return {
            ...cur,
            options: option,
        }
    })];
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use map function to resolve your query.

```js
var arr = [
{name: "audio", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "video", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]},
{name: "call", options:[{name:'true', value: 'T'},{name:'false', value: 'F'},{name:'yes', value: 'Y'}]}]
    

let result = [];
arr.map(a => {
  a.options.map(o => {
    result.push({ name: a.name, options: { ...o }
    });
  });
});
console.log(result)
```